# ¿Está mal utilizar muchos IF y no ELSEIF?

Tags: php

Si utilizo muchos `if` en vez de utilizar `if...elseif...elseif...`, ¿está 'inoptimizado' o mal?

Dejo un ejemplo:

```
// Opción 1: if
if($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '1')  { $ZonaIdioma = '1'; }
if($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '2')  { $ZonaIdioma = '2'; }
if($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '3')  { $ZonaIdioma = '3'; }
if($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '4')  { $ZonaIdioma = '4'; }
if($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '5')  { $ZonaIdioma = '5'; }
if($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '6')  { $ZonaIdioma = '6'; }
if($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '7')  { $ZonaIdioma = '7'; }
if($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '8')  { $ZonaIdioma = '8'; }
if($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '9')  { $ZonaIdioma = '9'; }
if($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '10') { $ZonaIdioma = '10'; }

// Opción 2: if..elseif
if($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '1')  { $ZonaIdioma = '1'; }
elseif($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '2')  { $ZonaIdioma = '2'; }
elseif($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '3')  { $ZonaIdioma = '3'; }
elseif($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '4')  { $ZonaIdioma = '4'; }
elseif($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '5')  { $ZonaIdioma = '5'; }
elseif($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '6')  { $ZonaIdioma = '6'; }
elseif($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '7')  { $ZonaIdioma = '7'; }
elseif($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '8')  { $ZonaIdioma = '8'; }
elseif($_REQUEST['Zone'] == '9')  { $ZonaIdioma = '9'; }
else { $ZonaIdioma = '10'; }
```

¿Está mal de la primera forma?

---

En concreto, necesito hacer una serie de `if` donde se traducen unos valores por otros. Pero no sé si poner:

```php
if($_REQUEST['Zone'] == 'casa')   { $ZonaIdioma = 'house'; }
if($_REQUEST['Zone'] == 'cocina') { $ZonaIdioma = 'kitchen'; }
if($_REQUEST['Zone'] == 'banio')  { $ZonaIdioma = 'bathroom'; }
```

O poner:

```php
if ($_REQUEST['Zone'] == 'casa')      { $ZonaIdioma = 'house'; }
elseif($_REQUEST['Zone'] == 'cocina') { $ZonaIdioma = 'kitchen'; }
elseif($_REQUEST['Zone'] == 'banio')  { $ZonaIdioma = 'bathroom'; }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y.. $_REQUEST['Zone'] esto puede tomar varios valores?? en un caso, que pasa? y en el otro? cuantas instrucciones se ejecutan en cada caso???

Comment: Solo necesitarías un if para verificar que el valor es adecuado: `if($_REQUEST['Zone'] >= 1 && $_REQUEST['Zone'] <= 10) { $ZonaIdioma = $_REQUEST['Zone']; }` Si el valor está entre 1 y 10, asignarlo a  `$ZonaIdioma`

Comment: @Triby pone eso en una respuesta, y de paso contale cuantas insturcciones se ejecutan entre poner solo if, o usar else if

Answer (score 5):

Tener `if` tras otro, sin `elseif`, hace que todos se procesen, independientemente de si alguno cumplió con la condición o no.

Pasarlos a `if ... elseif` resulta un poco mejor, aunque tampoco es lo adecuado, porque se van a realizar comparaciones hasta que una se cumpla, puede ser la primera o la última, dependiendo del valor recibido.

No es que te vaya a afectar en el rendimiento del script, simplemente vas a generar mucho código innecesario y va a ser muy complicado el mantenimiento conforme tengas que agregar, modificar o eliminar elementos.

Lo óptimo es crear un arreglo asociativo `nombre => traducción` y verificar que el parámetro se recibió y es válido, de lo contrario, quedar con un valor por defecto:

```
// Definir todos los valores posibles con su respectiva traducción
$valores = [
  'casa' => 'house',
  'cocina' => 'kitchen',
  'baño' => 'bathroom',
  'recámara' => 'bedroom'
];

// Definir valor por default
$ZonaIdioma = '(No disponible)';

// Verificar que se proporcionó un valor y existe en las traducciones
if(isset($_REQUEST['Zone']) && isset($valores[$_REQUEST['Zone']])) {
    $zonaIdioma = $valores[$_REQUEST['Zone']];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Es que depende de lo que quieras hacer, la diferencia es que usando elseif, solo se va a ejecutar una de las condiciones (la primera que se encuentre), mientras que con else, se pueden ejecutar todas las condiciones que se cumplan. 
En tu caso, elseif es lo recomedable porque solo una de las condiciones es posible que se cumpla.
Si necesitas traducir una cosa a otra, En ese caso podrías definir un array asociativo:

```
$traduccion = ['casa' => 'house', 'cocina' => 'kitchen' ... etc]
```

y luego:

```
$zonaIdioma = $traduccion[$_REQUEST['Zone']]
```

Si necesitas un valor por defecto, entonces puedes verificar primero si $_REQUEST['Zone'] tiene algún valor, y ahí sí agregar un solo if

Comment: El valor de $_REQUEST va a ser uno solo, y es una palabra, por ejemplo Casa entonces yo necesito traducirla

if($_REQUEST['Zone'] == 'casa')  { $ZonaIdioma = 'house'; }
if($_REQUEST['Zone'] == 'cocina')  { $ZonaIdioma = 'kitchen'; }
if($_REQUEST['Zone'] == 'banio')  { $ZonaIdioma = 'bathroom'; }

Comment: Edité la respuesta para adaptarla a tu problema.

Comment: Quedo rara la descripcion.. podes mejorarla? no queda claro cuando se ejecuta uno solo y cuando todos...

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como lo expones ambas formas son correctas (funcionan). Utilizar sólo el IF va a evaluar todos los casos no es muy óptimo. Con el ELSE IF una vez encontrada la condición verdadera deja de evaluar por lo que es mejor en cuanto a rendimiento. Lo más óptimo -y sencillo- me parece, es hacer un Switch
Por lo que el código luego va a ser más legible al final y no tienes que repetir tanto la variable en el código.

El código tendría para empezar una estructura así:

```
<?php 
switch($_REQUEST['Zone']){
    case 0: 
        $ZonaIdioma = '0'; 
        break;
    case 1:
        $ZonaIdioma = '1'; 
        break;
    case 2:
        $ZonaIdioma = '2'; 
        break;
    default:
        /*esta parte es como un else*/
        ;
         }
```